# Application variables in Classic asp running on Windows 2012 iis 8

Tags: iis, asp-classic, windows-server-2012

I just migrated classic ASP apps from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012. The IIS 8 role is also installed. The ASP and session support are all turned on. For some reason this particular app just cannot see it's application variables that are defined in its global.asa, while all other apps' application variables defined in their respective global.asa can be seen by ASP pages.  Interestingly when this application runs in locahost the application variables are seen by its ASP pages and the app works fine. It just doesn't work in non-localhost environment.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably a really stupid question, but: have converted the folder to an application (right click the ASP folder in the tree and select *Convert to Application*)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the app is already converted to an application and running on an application pool with .NET CLR Version version v2.0.50727 in classic pipeline mode.

Comment: This doesn't sound like asp-classic.

Comment: what do you mean, Martha?

Comment: @Martha: It is possible that this is a Classic ASP app, as the version of .NET does display for Classic ASP apps. It's a bit of a throw back from when ASP.NET required fixed libraries on the server.

Comment: Today I just realized that the original file structure has a folder with "&" in it.  For example, "Departments\A&F".  None of the folders below that point can be converted to application.  There many pages having links to the application in question.  We did a workaround by creating an application immediately below the root web.  So instead of accessing it with 
https://myorg.org/department/a&f/appInQuestion/index.asp, 
it will run with 
https://myorg.org/appInQuestion/Index.asp.

What's the easest way to create make new applications under the root web for those buried deep inside departments.